# Parsing json into Java Pojos with Gson from Kotlin is missing generic information

Tags: java, gson, kotlin

I'm having an issue with Java types and Gson, when being called from Kotlin

The Java POJO's representing an API response and it's errors

```
public class ApiResponse {

  @SerializedName("errors")
  public List<ApiResponseError> errors;
}


public class ApiResponseError {

  @SerializedName("code")
  public Integer code;

  @SerializedName("message")
  public String message;
}
```

The http response body on the wire

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "code": 10002,
      "message": "Not found"
    }
  ]
}
```

The kotlin code using Gson to parse the response into objects.

```
val errorResponse = Gson().fromJson<ApiResponse>(jsonBody, ApiResponse::class.java)
```

`jsonBody` is the string representation of the http response body on the previous snippet.

The debugger view of instantiated objects:

[image]

The problem is that the `ArrayList` should contain a `ApiResponseError` object and not a `LinkedTreeMap`.

I tried the same code without the generic type on the `List<ApiResponseError> errors` list, and the result is the same, so I am guessing the generic information is being lost somewhere and Gson is defaulting to `LinkedTreeMap`.

Any clues? Thanks

Comment: The code works on my computer.

Comment: What do you mean with "works" ? Does the `ArrayList` contains objects of type `ApiResponseError` or `LinkedTreeMap` ?

Comment: Just works as what you expect. Contain objects of type ApiResponseError.

Comment: I get same result as @aristotll. My gson version is `2.8.1`. Do you write your own extension function for `Gson.fromJson(String)`?

Comment: And I removed the comma after `"Not found",`, but it seems not to be related.

Comment: @BakaWaii yeah that extra comma is a typo, shouldn't be there. ` Gson().fromJson` is not an extension function, is a new instance of Gson being created and called upon. Gson is on version 2.8.0